# How to get multiple line input from Text Area and store it in array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, awt

I am working with netbeans on an applet. My problem is that I want to take multiple lines input (possibly from text area) and then output to another (text area).
My code in an application would look something like this. How to use the same concept with an applet?

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    picks[i]=br.readLine();
  picks[i] = picks[i].toUpperCase(); //picks is an array
  }
  /*
  .
  Some computations is happening here for picks[]
  .
  */

  for (int p=0;p<size;p++)
    {
            System.out.print(picks[p]);
            System.out.print("\n");     }
    }
```

I need to take each inputed line on its own and store it in the array and do the same with the output.
Thanks

Comment: this is at least the 10th gimmithecodez question today - and the answer is always the same: It's **you** who has to do **your** homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I am working with netbeans on an applet. My problem is that I want to take multiple lines input (possibly from text area) and then output to another (text area)."

Ok so you have two `JTextAreas`.  You probably want a button to click to transfer the text. So lets add the `actionPerformed` code as you would been in Netbeans

Right-click on the button (from design view) and select `Events -> Action -> actionPerformed`. The following code will be auto-generated:

```
public void jButton1aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}
```

Now all you need is a one-liner

```
public void jButton1aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextArea2.setText(jTextArea1.getText());
}
```

[image]

---

If you *really, really* want to store the text into an array, then just `.split` with the nex-line carriage character `"\n"`

```
String[] lines = jtextField1.getText().split("\\n");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly why I needed this. I need to store the string because I am changing it first and comparing it etc.